# how do I make page viewer and grid view scrollable together?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have ViewPager and grid view in my layout.for now only grid view is scrolling below the page ViewPager.how can I make both scrollable as vertical ?I used nested scrollable but nothing worked..so guide me..

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:id="@+id/viewpagermain"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

  </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
<View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="2dp"
  android:background="#c0c0c0"/>
 <GridView
  android:id="@+id/mGridView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingTop="5dp"
  android:paddingLeft="5dp"
  android:paddingRight="5dp"
  android:numColumns="auto_fit"
  android:columnWidth="172dp"
  android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
  android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
  android:background="#ffffff">
</GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: NestedScrollView as the name suggests is used when there is a need for a scrolling view inside another scrolling view.

Comment: Try android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView with option ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(scrollable, false);